# Whitelist Simulated phishing landing page

Tags: phishing, whitelist

We are running a simulated phishing campaign and one of the landing pages has been blacklisted by google. If you try to visit it in chrome you get the big, red warning page "Deceptive site ahead" (works OK in other browsers).

I assume one of our users reported it, thinking it was a real phishing page (kudos for that!) but now we have the problem that other users who are clicking the links in the emails we send are seeing the warning and not continuing, so we are not collecting data on them, or testing to see if they would go further and enter their credentials. Most importantly, we are missing the opportunity to train users who need that training!

I followed the "report a detection problem" link last week but the domains are still blacklisted. This is my question:

> Is there a way to whitelist our landing pages with google and the other browser makers, so even though they look like phishing pages, they don't get blacklisted in the future?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to whitelist our landing pages with google and the other browser makers, so even though they look like phishing pages, they don't get blacklisted in the future?

I think this would be a pretty bad idea. Just imagine if hackers could white list their public phishing pages this way.

If your control the way your users go into the internet you might use an internal DNS server which returns a different (local) IP address for the phishing domain for internal users. This internal site can then serve the phishing stuff while the external site is innocent. To make even more sure that it does not get blocked you might also try to use a top level domain which does not exist externally and is only resolved by your internal DNS server.

Comment: I see why it's a bad idea. Unfortunately our users are not all internal so we cannot implement your suggestion (+1 for a great idea though). The big phishing vendors like KnowBe4 must have a solution to this problem...